# Meteor proxy file to browser

Tags: meteor

I have a file at an external URL (which only the server meteor is running on can access)

```
http://192.168.9.39/account_5.pdf
```

I want to serve this up in meteor so that a user can click a link to e.g `http://server.meteor.com/temp/account_5.pdf`

Is there a way I can do this? Perhaps stream it directly to the user or download the file to the `/public/temp` folder so that it can be served up? How would I do this?

I'm open to any suggestions even if it uses up a node module or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your own Meteor server, or do you actually want to deploy to *.meteor.com?  (You said "server.meteor.com", so I was wondering).

From node you could use [http.get](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) to retrieve the remote file and then use [fs.writeFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_encoding_callback) to save it to your temp/ directory.

Or you could stream it like you suggested using something like http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/

If you're running your own server, probably the easiest thing would be to package up this code in a small npm module.  Node's `require` is exposed to Meteor code in `__meteor_bootstrap__.require`, so to trigger fetching the remote file you could do something like `__meteor_bootstrap__.require('my-npm-module').fetchFileToTemp(name)`.

For the streaming option, `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` is Meteor's connect server, which you can attach your own requests handlers to via

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app(function (req, res, next) { ... });
```

in the usual way for connect middleware.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the pdf in your /public folder and deploy, users can just click http://server.meteor.com/account_5.pdf to access the pdf.

Is this what you're expecting? Hope that's helpful.

Comment: I have to download it into the public folder from the remote one first. I'm not quite sure how to do this with meteor, I don't think it has file handling does it?. The file is generated by the remote machine so I can't manually put each one in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hackish, but you could make a route (with Meteor Router) that responds to `/temp/*` and put an iframe in those pages that loads the remote URL. It won't be elegant, but it will work! In case you need this done quick.

Or you could do a cross-origin XHR request and go fetch the file that way, which is probably more Meteor-ish. But I'd have to look that one up. ;-)

Comment: I like this idea but im not too sure how to do it in meteor, perhaps I can write a package to help. Do packages have access to stuff like file handles (so it can be used on meteor.com for example)?